# How to fix this non-compiling method?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Doing some practice exam questions, and it says to:

> assume the statement `String pattern = getPattern();`. Explain if any flow in the method getPattern(). How would you fix it?

Here's the code:

```
public static String getPattern() {
  Scanner inPattern = new Scanner(System.in);
  String pattern = " ";
  boolean valid = false;
  int i = 0;
  while(!valid){
    System.out.println("please enter a valid pattern with X or x");
    pattern = inPattern.next();
 if ( !  (pattern.charAt(i) == 'X' || pattern.charAt(i) == 'x'
    || pattern.charAt(i) == 'r'))
    System.out.println("You have entered an invalid pattern");
else if ((i + 1) == pattern.length()) valid = true;
};
inPattern.close();
return pattern;
}
```

I'm not really sure how I would fix this... obviously this is a smaller part of a bigger code because this doesn't include a main method, personally making it a bit more difficult to see what's wrong.

I'm really not sure exactly what to change here. I've been up for 7+ hours watching youtube videos and attempting to understand this stuff or to do this question but I really cannot figure it out.  would anyone be able to provide a good example?

Comment: "non-compiling method?" -- Do you get an error message? Add it to your post.

Comment: **Explain if any flow in the method getPattern(). How would you fix it?** Is this _really_ the question? It's nonsense as it's not a complete sentence. Also, when posting questions such as this, you should post compiler errors. They will tell you why it doesn't compile.

Comment: 'Flow'? Do you mean 'flaw'?

Answer (score 0):

Okey, so first things first. The code you recieved is all you need to run it, its not part of a "bigger program". It tells you to assume its being called like this:

```
String pattern = getPattern();
```

So when calling the method "getPattern" from a main method what happens? You get prompted to input a "valid" character, if the character is valid the method returns the character.

The question itself is weirdly designed. But looking at the code, I guess what they're fishing for is that you're being told to input the character 'x' or 'X'. But in the code another valid character is 'r'. So either they want you to change the text given to the user, or remove 'r' as a valid char would be my guess.